# Having difficulty with Binomial Probabilities qustion

Tags: statistics

I've never worked with binomial probabilities before and  I found this question below a little hard. If anyone could help that would be great.

*Use Binomial Probabilities to find probability that for the certain number of trials N and probability of success in each trial p
number of successes will be:*

1) exactly k 
2) less than k 
3) more than k

**N: 10 k 6 P: 0.5**

Use numbers assigned to N, K, P

Answer (score 1):

Hint/partial answer: for a binomial probability where $X$ is the number of successes and $p$ is the probability of success, $P(X=k)={N \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$.

To get less than $k$ you have to add up several of these probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The probability mass function (PMF) for a binomially distributed random variable, $X\sim \mathcal{Bin}(N, p)\;$, is: $$\mathsf P(X= k) = \dbinom{N}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k} \qquad [k\in\{0..N\}]$$

From that you have the cumulative distribution function (CDF): $$\mathsf P(X\leq k) = \sum_{j=0}^k \dbinom{N}{j} p^j(1-p)^{N-j} \qquad [k\in\{0..N\}]$$

And thusly: $\mathsf P(X<k) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1} \dbinom{N}{j} p^j(1-p)^{N-j} \qquad [k\in\{1..N\} \\ \mathsf P(X>k) = \sum\limits_{j=k+1}^N \dbinom{N}{j} p^j(1-p)^{N-j} \qquad [k\in\{0..N-1\}]$

Everything else is just substituting values into the appropriate formula and calculating.